# Django Filters not querying data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter API responses through a web search. After typing a search query it doesn't filter the result. I'm also using pagination. How to solve this do I need to make changes in my filter or View.

search query

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/course-api/subjectlist/?search="ICT"/
```

after giving this search query still it returns all of the elements through the response.

Subject model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    def upload_location(instance, filename):
        return "subject_images/%s/%s" % (instance.subject_name, filename)

    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    subject_cover = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_location,default="subject_images/default.png")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(TeacherProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None)
    subject_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    class_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from ..models import Subject

class SubjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['subject_name']
```

Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def SubjectList(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size=5
    subjects =SubjectFilter ( request.GET, queryset= Subject.objects.all())
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(subjects.queryset,request)
    serializer = SubjectViewSerializer(result_page,many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: The filter uses the name of the fields as query-parameter in your url. So try http://127.0.0.1:8000/course-api/subjectlist/?subject_name=ICT

Comment: It's still giving me the same result

Comment: Without the pagination, it's working when I give the subject_name as the query variable

Comment: Hi, ```subjects.queryset``` contains the unfiltered data. ```subjects.qs``` contains the filtered data. In your case, you filter the data but proceed to paginate with the initial queryset. Try ```result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(subjects.qs, request)```.